# Connection closed unexpectedly: Nodemailer

Tags: smtp, nodemailer

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');


//Middleware
app.use(express.static('frontend'));

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/frontend/index.html');
});
app.post('/', (req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    const transporter1 = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service:"gmail",
        host: "smtp.gmail.com", // hostname
        secure: false, // use SSL
        port: 587, // port for secure SMTP
        auth: {
            user: "my email id",
            pass: "mypassword"
        },
        tls: {
            ciphers: "SSLv3",
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
        },
    });
   
    const mailOptions = {
        from:req.body.email,
        to: 'prahlad.hsrao@gmail.com',
        cc: '24septanjali@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Form Information',
        text:"firstName: "+ req.body.fname+"\n" + "lastName"+req.body.lname+"email" + req.body.email+"phone"+req.body.phone+"message"+req.body.message,
        
    }
    transporter1.sendMail(mailOptions,(error,info)=>{
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.send('error');
            transporter1.close();
        }
        else{
            console.log('Email sent' + info.response);
            res.send('success'); 
            res.redirect('/');
            transporter1.close();   
        }
        
    })
})
app.listen(3000,()=>console.log('Server started...'));
```

---

firstly it was working perfectly, I send the email successfully 5-6 time, then while trying to send the mail, it is giving following error.
Error: Connection closed unexpectedly
at SMTPConnection._onClose (D:\official\SendEmailProject\nodeContactForm\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:827:34)
at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketClose (D:\official\SendEmailProject\nodeContactForm\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:193:42)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
at node:net:757:14
at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:584:7) {
code: 'ECONNECTION',
command: 'CONN'

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error. After searching I guess it's a problem with the email server. I got about 5% of all my auto emails to fail. Maybe we can try to change one.